# How to Stop Event Happens After One time

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please let me know why I am not able to control the event on `div` until button click event happen?
Basically what I need to is only one event happens on `div` after the `button` clicked
 I tried to control this with Boolean `clickEvtHandler` but it didnt go through

```js
var clickEvtHandler = false;
var i = 1;
$("button").on("click", function() {
  clickEvtHandler = true;
  if (clickEvtHandler) {
    $("div").on("click", function() {
      $(this).append(i++);
      clickEvtHandler = false;
    });
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>
  Enable Event On Div
</button>
<div></div>
```

Comment: using off? http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: Remove `clickEvtHandler = true;` from the event handler function, and set `clickEvtHandler` to `true` outside of the handler.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use event only once then go for

```
$( "#div" ).one( "click", function() {
  alert( "This will be displayed only once." );
});
```

Above code will make sure that event bonded to given div will execute **exactly once.**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use two seperate handlers:

```
var clickEvtHandler = false, i = 1;

$("button").on("click", function() {
  clickEvtHandler = true;
});

$("div").on("click", function() {
  if (!clickEvtHandler) return;
  $(this).append(i++);
  clickEvtHandler = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var clickEvtHandler = false;
var i = 1;

$("button").on("click", function() {
    clickEvtHandler = true;
    if (clickEvtHandler) {
        $("div").on("click", function() {
            if (clickEvtHandler)
                $(this).append(i++);
                clickEvtHandler = false;
        });
    }
});
```